# Not able to make TURN work properly in wire-server

Tags: ubuntu, turn

I'm trying to setup Wire-server on EC2 with Ubuntu. Everything has been set up and working fine. But when trying to make an audio or video call, it gets disconnected without any error.

I've followed this:
https://nil.uniza.sk/installing-and-configuring-restund-stunturn-server/

and used 127.0.0.1 as the Ip as I'm setting up the TURN on the same server. Am I supposed to use a different IP or set it up on a different server?

TURN is working fine on port 3478.

If I open two different accounts on the same device that is one in incognito mode, then the call is working excellent. But the call is not being connected to another user on a different device and it gets cut off after going to connecting... state.